# Integrals and f(x)dx

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose

$$\int_0^2 f(x)\,dx=3,\\
\int_0^5 f(x)\,dx=8.$$

Compute

$$\int_2^5 f(x)\, dx,\\
    \int_0^2 f(2x)\,dx.$$

For the first one, I know that by subtraction

$$\int_2^5 f(x)\,dx = \int_0^5 f(x)\,dx - \int_0^2 f(x)\,dx= 8-3=5.$$

My question is what do I do in the second? The $f(2x)$ really throws me off

Comment: I remember this was asked recently.

Comment: Substituting $u = 2x$ gives you $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2}f(2x)\,dx = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{4}f(u)\,du$, but I don't think you have enough information to evaluate that.

Comment: TLI = "too little information" to resolve the problem.

Comment: Do we have any other information e.g. f(x) is a linear function

Comment: no that is the entire problem, maybe TLI is the answer, thanks for all help

Comment: Are you *positive* that the bounds on the second expression were not different? i.e. that it was not $\displaystyle \int_0^4 f(2x)dx$ or $\displaystyle \int_0^{10} f(2x)dx$ that they wanted you to find?

Comment: Yes, but how would that make it different? Maybe it was a typo from the professor, I'd love to know how to fix the problem

Comment: @user3566906 It would make it vastly different. The problem would become immediately solvable by a simple substitution (try $u = 2x$, remembering to transform both the variable of integration as well as the bounds). BTW, if you're replying to my comment, you should direct my attention to it by using the '@' symbol followed by my username. It's lucky I went back over my activity, otherwise I would've missed your reply.

Comment: @Deepak thanks, didnt know that, and thanks for the help

Comment: @user3566906 No problem (and I did get alerted this time. :) )

Answer (score 2):

You use substitution. Take $v=2x$, thus $dx=\frac12 dv$. Hence,
$$
\int_0^2f(2x)\,dx=\frac12\int_0^4 f(v)\,dv.
$$
However, from the given integrals, there is not enought information to evaluate this integral.